# gradient on curve not working

Tags: materials

so i got [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/3yXpqVzd/) gradient setup to put a gradient on a curve, but the gradient doesn't show up. i messed around with the position, angle, and even the scale, and yet it still doesn't work. it's helpful to note that i'm using a circle as a bevel object so i'm guessing that because of the bevel object it won't work. i have also enabled uv mapping on the curve and blender 2.79 is the version i'm working with.

[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you tweak the Rotation values of the Mapping node?

Comment: i slid all the rotation values past 360° and it still doesn't show the gradient

Comment: Here is what I get with Rotation > 0/-45/45, but maybe share your file? https://zupimages.net/up/23/23/wbyj.jpg

Comment: i tried to mess around with the rotation after i switched the thing from uv to texture, and all it seems to do is make the curve a certain color when i mess with the rotation, [here](https://file.io/e5Q5oV1s9k5G) is the file, i deleted the main model (cause i deffo can't spill the sauce) but the curve and the circle are there still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default UV space of a curve is **U**: 0-1 down the length, and **V**: 0-1 around its circumference (even if the curve is bevelled with another curve). You use the X and Y of a *Separate XYZ* node to get at those components.

At the moment you're plugging a vector (UV output) into a scalar (*Color Ramp* input) which would normally average the U and V, resulting in a diagonal gradient.. but in this case it's scaled to 0 in your *Mapping* node, so you're getting nothing.

If you want a gradient down the length of your curve, use its **U** (X) to control the output from the ramp:

[image]

If you want the other gradient, around the profile, use the **V** (Y)

Comment: ok so this helped and it turns out the gradient only shows when i switch on the render view

Comment: Go ahead and share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/, (Edit the provided link into your question)